# How to generate a table which links a turtle-own variable to ticks and updates this value after after 24 ticks

Tags: netlogo

I'm fairly new to Netlogo but I want to build a model where an agent (a car driver) tracks a certain turtle-own variable (utility) in each hour of the day. I linked the ticks to the hours so one day has 24 ticks.

I plan to integrate two things:

- First, the idea is that an agent tracks its utility of a certain action (in my model this would be the utility the agent obtains by charging) at a specific hour in one day and then uses this utility-value for future charge-or-not-charge decisions. My initial approach was to create a table where each row represent one hour (in total there should be 24 rows) and the column represents the observed turtle-own variable (in this case: utility).
- Second, the values in the column should be updated after every day (let's say that we have stored a utility-value for Monday 01:00 am (tick #1), then after one day this utility-value should be updated by the utility-value obtained on Tuesday 01:00 (tick #25). Here, I would use *foreach* to replace the old value by the new one.

```
turtle-own [utility]

to setup
  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks

  ;; set the start date to January 1, 2020 and link the ticks to one hour
  set start-time time:create "2020/01/01 00:00"
  set current-time time:anchor-to-ticks start-time 1.0 "hour"
  time:anchor-schedule start-time 1.0 "hour"
end

to setup-turtles
ask turtles [
  set utility 0
]
end

to go
ask turtles [
  set utility utility + 1 ; just a placeholder for now - I'm still working on the true utility-function
]
end
```

But I struggle with implementing the first step, since I cannot link every hour to the turtle-own variable "utility".

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is for the turtle to store 24 values of utility (1 for each hour), then utility can be a list instead of a single number. You can access the appropriate hour's value with `item`, so you might have something:

```
let hours ticks mod 24
let new-value 1 + item hours utility
replace-item hours utility new-value
```

Note that you will need to have values in your list before you can access them. For example, referring to `item 9` when your list only has 5 values will generate an error. Also, NetLogo is 0-indexed. This means that the first value in the list is accessed with `item 0`, not `item 1`.

A couple of observations as you mentioned you are new to NetLogo. It is very unlikely you need the time extension for this model. If you are basically using a constant time step of one hour, then just use `tick` in the normal way. Even if you do eventually need to use the time extension as you build a more complicated model that refers to real time in some way, you can add it then. You also mentioned `foreach` - that primitive is used to loop through a list, which you do not need to do. It sounds like you would be looping through the list of utility values to represent the change in time - if so, do not do this. Look at some example models in the NetLogo library and try and understand how time works. You should also understand the separation between the setup procedure and go procedure in these models, the go procedure contains all the things that have to happen during a time step. You will need `ticks` (current time step) and `tick` (advance to next time step). I cannot emphasise enough how important it is to understand this in any simulation.